# Why are 2 of the functions in the kotlin media session callbacks sample public?

Tags: android, kotlin

On the android developer guides for the media session callbacks, 2 of the listed functions in the sample code show as  `public override fun`, external to the media session callback object.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/mediasession-callbacks#kotlin

Is this a mistake in the documentation, or is there something missing from my understanding here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the Kotlin and Java versions of that code, it seems the Kotlin one has misplaced curly braces, leaving the `onStop()` and `onPause()` functions out of the `MediaSessionCompat.Callback` overrides block. If it was to be fixed, what you'd see there is they need to respect the overriden functions' visibility, so they can't be private or protected.